# Clojure: What is the meaning of ` and ~@?

Tags: clojure

I am working through the [problems at 4Clojure](https://www.4clojure.com/problems).

I have a working solution for the [Tic-Tac-Toe exercise](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/73), but I can't understand [Darren's](https://www.4clojure.com/user/darren) solution:

```
(fn [b]
  (some (fn [p] (first (keep #(if (apply = p %) p)
                         `(~@b                   ; <- What is that ` and ~@?
                           ~@(apply map list b)  ; 
                           ~(map get b [0 1 2])
                           ~(map get b [2 1 0])))))
     [:x :o]))
 ;b is a two-dimensional vector
```

What is the meaning of ` and ~@?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**` is the syntax-quote**, which is used to write code as data without evaluating it. Note that it is clever enough to resolve symbols that represent functions to the correct namespace.

Examples:

```
`(+ 1 2)
=> (clojure.core/+ 1 2)    ; a list containing the + function and two arguments

(eval `(+ 1 2))
=> 3                       ; the result of evaluating the list
```

**~@ is the unquote-splicing operator**, which will enable you to expand a list of elements within some quoted data/code.

Examples:

```
(def args [3 4 5 6])

`(+ 1 2 ~@args 7 8)
=> (clojure.core/+ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)

`(+ ~@(range 10))
=> (clojure.core/+ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

More detail on both of these and related operations can be found as part of the [documentation for the Clojure reader](http://clojure.org/reader).

Comment: It seems to me that `~@` is only useful inside syntax-quote'd seq. Am I right?

Comment: Yes - I believe ~@ is only defined within a quoted context. The two work pretty much hand in hand. Same goes for ~.

Answer (score 2):

See the "Syntax-quote" bullet-pointed section and examples in the [documentation on the reader](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters).

Answer (score 2):

Even though it is Common Lisp, and not Clojure, the chapter on macros in Practical Common Lisp has some good examples that translate well:

http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html